# Auto-refresh Derived Tables in BigQuery web UI

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the BigQuery Web UI to derive several custom tables from our firebase app event data (one big messy table).  This allows other display services (in this case Google Data Studio) to display dynamic dashboards and reports.

The problem is that I can't get my derived tables to auto-update each morning.  Instead I have to manually re-run the queries in order to refresh the data.  Is there a way to configure these jobs to run in the interface?  Or do I have to configure jobs somewhere else? Thanks.

Comment: No there is no tool to configure on UI, you need to run somewhere else using the API + libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not as simple as scheduled table materialization, you could set up a cron in Google App Engine to kick off your daily query job. I believe this should easily remain within the free tier.

There are docs for both [Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) and [Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron).

It looks like you can schedule daily tasks with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) as well.

Here is a quick example I tried.

- Go to: script.google.com
- Enable advanced services (Menu > Resources > Advanced Services ..., then turn on BigQuery).
- Name the default function something more descriptive, I chose "rebuildTables".
- Click the "triggers" button (looks like a clock with a tack sticking out of it).
- Give your project a name. I chose "BigQuery -- Build Daily Tables".
- Now you can add a trigger. For example: time-driven, day timer, 5am to 6am
- Edit the script. Borrowed from here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery

```js
function rebuildTables() {
  // Replace this value with the project ID listed in the Google
  // Developers Console project.
  var projectId = 'EXAMPLE_PROJECT';

  var request = {
    configuration: {
      query: {
        query: 'SELECT 17;',
        destinationTable: {
          "projectId": "EXAMPLE_PROJECT",
          "datasetId": "EXAMPLE_DATASET",
          "tableId": "EXAMPLE_TABLE"
        },
        writeDisposition: "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
      }
    }    
  };

  // Fire-and-forget.
  BigQuery.Jobs.insert(request, projectId);
}
```

Comment: This is great.  Easy enough to do in Python it looks like.  Thanks much!