# How to tell there is new data available in ga_sessions_intraday_ efficiently

Tags: google-bigquery

Google Analytics data should be exported to Big Query 3 times a day, according to [the docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089).  I trying to determine an efficient way to detect new data is available in the ga_sessions_intraday_ table and run a query in BQ to extract on the new data.

My best idea is to poll ga_sessions_intraday_ by running a SQL query every hour.  I would track the max visitStartTime (storing the state somewhere) and if a new max visitStartTime shows up in the ga_sessions_intraday_ then I would run my full queries.

Problems with this approach is I need to store state about the max visitStartTime.  I would prefer something simpler.

Does GA Big Query have a better way of telling that new data is available in ga_sessions_intraday_?  Some kind of event that fires?  Do I use the last modified date of the table (but I need to keep track of the time window to run against)?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Kevin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Last modified time on the table is probably the best approach here (and cheaper than issuing a probe query). I don't believe there is any other signalling mechanism for delivery of the data.

If your full queries run more quickly than your polling interval, you could probably just use the modified time of your derived tables to hold the data (and update when your output tables are older than your input tables).

[Metadata queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#using_meta-tables) are free, so you can even embed most of the logic in a query:

```
SELECT
  (
  SELECT
    MAX(last_modified_time)
  FROM
    `YOUR_INPUT_DATASET.__TABLES__`) >
  (
  SELECT
    MAX(last_modified_time)
  FROM
    `YOUR_OUTPUT_DATASET.__TABLES__`) need_update
```

If you have a mix of tables in your output dataset, you can be more selective (with a WHERE clause) to filter down the tables you examine.

If you need a convenient place to run this scheduling logic (that isn't a developer's workstation), you might consider [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252095/auto-refresh-derived-tables-in-bigquery-web-ui/39380145#39380145). (Short version: Apps Script is pretty neat)

You might also consider filing a feature request for "materialized views" or "scheduled queries" on BigQuery's [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list). I didn't see a existing entry for this with a quick skim, but I've certainly heard similar requests in the past.

I'm not sure how the Google Analytics team handles feature requests, but having a pubsub notification upon delivery of a new batch of Analytics data seems like it could be useful as well.

Comment: *"Metadata queries are free"*. Interesting. Do you have any source for this? I cannot find it in the link in your post. I do see in the Google documentation that metadata **operations** are free, but I don't see how this applies to queries. What happens if you combine the `__TABLES__` table with regular tables? Would love to read more about this.